# Angularjs POST method returns 404 error in console

Tags: angularjs, post

I am trying to write the data with the POST method through api on: http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies. I have tried various things from the stack, This is my code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.SendData = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                id: $scope.id,
                name: $scope.name,
                city: $scope.city,
             });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post('http://localhost:4567/api/v1/companies', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                    "<hr />status: " + status +
                    "<hr />headers: " + header +
                    "<hr />config: " + config;
            });
        };

    });
</script>
</head>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HttpGetController">
    <p>ID: <input type="number" name="id" ng-model="id" required /></p>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" required /></p>
    <p>City: <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="city" required /></p>
    <button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>
    <hr />
    {{ PostDataResponse }}
</div>
```

In the console i got 404 error.[image: Screen shot of the console]

[image: Server side(Sinatra)]

Comment: slightly off topic but why do you use angularjs not angular2/4/5?

Comment: Change Content-Type to application/json and check.

Comment: I tried to change Content-Type, but no success. @mast3rd3mon I am using it because that is a requirement

Comment: ah ok, seems a bit of an annoying requirement though, especially when angular2/4/5 is newer and a lot better/nicer to use

Answer (score 0):

The options request you see there is indicative of CORS.  When the client code and server come from different domains or ports it will do an OPTIONS request before sending the POST so you just need to allow any domain to request things from your server side by adding the appropriate headers to accept connections from anywhere.  You said you are using node I believe in another question:

https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

The 404 response to the OPTIONS request is stopping the browser from doing anything further but this is basically between the browser and the server and the server needs to give the correct response to the OPTIONS request or the browser will give up.

So you either enable that on the server or have the server send the client files on the same domain/port as the server API comes from and then it's also not an issue.

Comment: Sinatra, I had a problem with GET. after adding appropriate heade I could read the data, so I think CORS is not the case here anymore

Comment: It is still a problem it is giving a 404 response for the request it needs to give a 200 OK if you enabled for GET just make sure you allow methods POST as well in your headers on the server.

Comment: I will post the screen shot from the server side, POST is allowed same as GET notice that GET works

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a 404 response, that is a page not found http code, seems like something is still wrong with the server configuration. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes  You might also want to just use express to statically serve the angular files as well to avoid CORs issues (personally use apache and typically laravel/php backend so the PHP-FPM processing is "proxied" through apache, you can do the same with nginx and node or any combo of those really).

Comment: So, you say that this code should actually work if the server side is correctly configured. That means that this code is correct?

Comment: Well CORS is between the browser and the server not really anything to do with your code aside from your code trying to initiate a post request.  You can take the browser out of the equation by using curl at the command line (posting is a bit more of a pain than getting but should work fine) regarding the code being correct not entirely sure but if you have no console errors it appears to be doing what you would expect aside from the 404 error on the OPTIONS request as far as I can tell.  Use `debugger` to add breakpoints in your code or drop breakpoints in the source panel in chrome to verify

Comment: I have slightly changed the code and now I am getting 400

Comment: Not super familiar with that backend but from your screenshots and config you've shown it appears it is giving the appropriate headers but the response should just be a 200 OK with nothing in the body for those OPTIONS requests.  Essentially you can just put a handler in for any OPTIONS request for your endpoint(s) to return these headers and a 200OK http status code and do nothing else with that OPTIONs request.  Once the browser gets a 200OK with the response headers you're showing it should fire off the actual POST with the data.